# Sram crankset compatibility

Tags: crankset, sram

I have a bike with SRAM s350 172.5mm 40T chainset, SRAM GXP 68mm BB and 12x142mm through axle rear hub, which should make my chainline 49mm.
As I have knee issues I am looking for 165mm crank arms (with 38T chainring). On SRAM site I see that Force 1 and GX-1000 crankset should fit, but I have 2 (actually 3) questions:

1. Does Rival 1 also fit those specs? As it works with 135mm rear hub (as written on SRAM web), shouldn't it work with 142mm rear hub as well, as they are basically the same? Also the Rival 1 is a lot less expensive and is more than I need so I would prefer to get that.
2. Do You know is there ANYWHERE in Europe that I could get some of these as I have searched every website I could think of and no one seems to have 165mm crankarms available?
3. What other 165mm 38T are available that are comparable to Rival 1 in price and spec?

I know it's a lot of questions but they sort of tie in to one another..I guess? :)

Thank You.

Comment: Don't forget about crank Q-factor, especially if your knees have preferences about it's optimal value. MTB cranksets like GX-1000 usually have it wider than road/CX cranks like Force 1 or Rival 1.

Comment: Note that shopping and product recommendation questions are off-topic, here, and most of your questions 2 and 3 seem to be in that category.

Comment: You are right about Q2, but Q3 is just a recommendation for another manufacturer, not a shop. The "price" bit is just so that it is from the same "range" so to speak. If price was not an issue I could just order some super expensive unobtanium alloy crank molded for my own feet botoms :)

Comment: @Klaster_1 Thanks for the advice, I forgot about that. I was mostly focusing on it fitting my frame and gear. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look up [SRAM S350-1](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/products/sram-s350-1-crankset) (single chain ring) on SRAM’s website it says that it is a direct replacement for Rival 1 and compatible with 130, 135, and 142 OLD frames.  Rival 1 should be a straight swap assuming you get the correct axle variant (i.e., GPX).

Comment: I did look. The problem is that under Rival 1 it says 130 and 135 and I wasn't sure that it is backwards compatible, although I presume it is. Do you have any experience in this? And yes it is GXP and I was looking for GXP variant.

Comment: @spiroX 135 Frame’s are quick release, while 142 are thru axel. Both fit hubs of the same effective width. The thru axel frame has a longer measurement because axel itself bolt into the frame and as such needs to be a bit longer. This is why many wheels now can swap end caps to fit either standard. Many new 142 bikes come with Rival 1.

Comment: @spiroX you will find manufacturer websites are notoriously inconsistent.

Comment: You are not kidding! O  Sram website it says that s350 is crankset for Apex 1 and that the smallest size is 170mm,and Rival 1 crankset smallest size is 165. As it turns out Rival 1 smallest size is 170, s350 smallest size is also 170,but there is another crankset called Apex 1 (which isn't even listed on the website) that comes in 165 but it has 4 hole chainring unlike the usual 5 hole 110 bcd. Seems I'll be ordering that one. I am only slightly concerned about future chainring availability as it isn't a standard like 5 hole 110 bcd.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my answer here:

https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=142287

> > > 142 thru axle and 135 quick release have the same measurement from midline of bike to cassette.This is what has been used for years on mountain bikes.
> > >
> > > 130 quick release is 2.5mm less from midline of bike to cassette. This is what has been used for years on road/CX bikes.

If Rival 1 fits then I'm not that interested in mixing other manufacturers, so Q3 is out, and as stated Q2 is about shopping so that one is out.

Thank You